# Given an int list, print a new list with double the length where its last element is the same as the original list, and all the other elements are 0

Tags: python, list

Attached is an image of a web application named pylab. We're currently using this for our assessments but i'm completely confused. Does anyone know how to get this problem to work?

[image]

Attempt 1:

```
x=int(input())
newList = []
for i in range(2*len(x)-1):
    y.append(0)

newList.append(x[-1])
print(newlist)
```

Attempt 2

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
newList = [a,b,c,d]
    for v in range newList:
        for i in range(2*len(v)-1):
            y.append(0)
    newList.append(v[-1])
print(newlist)
```

[Failed Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoeEq.png)
[How Printing Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0llWf.png)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not how StackOverflow works. This is your homework and you should at least try to do something.

Comment: I have attempted it multiple times and the platform itself isn't supportive of the usual style of coding. I've gotten this correct with a normal list and a function I've created on pycharm, but no luck with "pylab". This is a site where you ask like minded people for their experience. Someone here has likely used 'pylab' before and that's who I'm asking. Not you who has no idea.

Comment: There will not be any issues if you kindly shared your attempts

Comment: I'll add my attempts because it'll amuse me. But i'm certain my first judgement that they would provide 0 help for someone unfamiliar with "pylab" still stands.

Comment: Is there a link for `pylab`? What is under `help` button? What is the `Actual output` for `print(input())` and `print(1)`?

Comment: @soon The 'help button' just talks about list and tuples.Included actual output above. print(1) would output 1

Comment: Try to firstly read number of elements in the list (`n`). Then iterate n times, each time read single value from `input()`. Then solve task and output the list elements separated by space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = input().split(' ')
b = []
for i in range(2*len(a)-1):
    b.append(0)

b.append(int(a[-1]))
print(*b)
```

or:

```
a = input().split(' ')
b = [int(a[-1]) if i == 2*len(a)-1 else 0 for i in range(2*len(a))]
print(*b)
```

Comment: Yeah my solution was similar to this, the problem I'm having is that the input pylab requires is weird. If you refer to the image there's an expected output there. I gotta try and achieve that but the inputs given aren't in list format and I can't just have multiple inputs assigned because each test has different inputs.

Comment: @RyanGrady I updated my answer. check if it is ok for you

Comment: I've upload a pic of your results vs's the type of input I think it wants. Might help.

Comment: Where did you upload it?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [4, 5, 6]
print([0] * (len(l) * 2 - 1) + l[-1:])
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def func(list):
   x = np.zeros(len(list*2))
   x[-1] = list[-1]
   return x


print(func([1, 2]))
```